# Missing data with prop.table

Tags: r

I am a R newbie, I am trying to get the proportions of a categorical covariate using prop.table, notwithstanding, this function gives to me the proportions of observations using the missing data. I wonder if anyone knows how to deal with this? Thank you in advance.

> summary(factor(Base_imi_rel_depurada_280418$IMPcateg >=1))

FALSE  TRUE  NA's 
   17    11     1

> prop.table (table(Base_imi_rel_depurada_280418$IMPcateg >=1))

```
FALSE      TRUE
```

0.6071429 0.3928571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `exclude=NULL` in the `table` function in order to keep the missing values.  This should give you the output you want:

`prop.table(table(Base_imi_rel_depurada_280418$IMPcateg >=1, exclude=NULL))`