# Displaying percentages within category for continuous/ordered variable (with ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, geom-col

I have two questions, the first a (hopefully) straightforward mechanical one and the second more theoretical (though still with a technical element).

1. I am trying to do something nearly identical to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71887769/calculating-percentages-within-category-using-geom-col), but I have a variable that is ordered/continuous (0 - 4), instead of a 1/0 dichotomous variable, which means that filtering == 1 will not work. To summarize here, I simply want to display the percent of each level within each race category.
2. I am also hoping to figure out a way to display those descriptive results for all 3 questions in just one figure. I first thought about trying to do some type of `facet_wrap()` with each variable (question1, question2, question3) being its own panel. Would that require `pivot_longer()` to make my data long instead of wide? Another thought was to have just one figure/panel, but each x axis tick is a race category instead of a question, and then it'd have 3 bars for each of the 3 questions. I'm not sure how I'd get that to work, though.

Thanks in advance and sorry for this wordy question. Here is some example data:

```
set.seed(123)

d <- data.frame(
  race = sample(c("White", "Hispanic", "Black", "Other"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  question1 = sample(0:4, 100, replace = TRUE),
  question2 = sample(0:4, 100, replace = TRUE),
  question3 = sample(0:4, 100, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```r
  library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
d <- data.frame(
  race = sample(c("White", "Hispanic", "Black", "Other"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  question1 = sample(0:4, 100, replace = TRUE),
  question2 = sample(0:4, 100, replace = TRUE),
  question3 = sample(0:4, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

d %>%
  pivot_longer(-race, names_to = "question", values_to = "vals") %>% 
  group_by(question, race, vals) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  group_by(question, race) %>% 
  mutate(pct = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=race, y=pct, fill=as.factor(vals))) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~question) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales:::percent) + 
  labs(x="", y="Percentage (within Race)", fill="Response") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "top", 
        panel.grid = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This...this is awesome. I always forget about tally(). I'll probably use position = dodge instead of stacked, but this is basically perfect. I really appreciate it!

Comment: a quick additional question: is there a way to exclude NAs from each individual -question- variable as I calculate percentages? In my real data, I have some NAs scattered throughout and don't want to drop entire rows, because some folks have NAs on one question and responses for the other two, for example. I can open a separate question thread if that's better, too.

Comment: @a_todd12 put `filter(!is.na(question)) %>%` after the `pivot_longer()` statement and that should do it.

Comment: Hm I think that isn't working for some reason, I'll keep trying. EDIT: I think it has to be !is.na(vals), instead of question, after ```pivot_longer()```.

Comment: Sorry, you're right @a_todd12.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a modification of @DaveArmstrong's very good solution+1:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)

sPalette <- "Purples" %>% 
  sapply(., function(x) brewer.pal(8, name = x)) %>% 
  as.vector

d %>% 
  pivot_longer(-race) %>%
  count(name, race, value) %>% 
  group_by(name, race) %>%
  mutate(value = as.factor(value),
         pct= prop.table(n) * 100) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=race, y=pct, fill=value)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_fill()) +
  facet_wrap(.~name)+
  labs(x="", y="Percentage (within Race)", fill="Response") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  geom_text(aes(label =  round(pct, 1)),
            position = position_fill(vjust = .5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = sPalette) + 
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = "top", 
        panel.grid = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @TarJae, I like the RColorBrewer here. A question about prop.table, which I haven't used before: how would I get it to handle NAs? In my real data I have some NAs strewn about, and I want to calculate the percentages who actually answered each question (aka excluding NAs, but not just dropping any row with an NA entirely).

Comment: Really nice - I like the printed values in the bars.  I always forget that you can do that so easily with `position_fill()`.  Great addition!

Comment: @a_todd12. I am not sure if this is what you are looking for <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50077433/missing-data-with-prop-table>. A good source to understand `prop.table` was for me <https://r-lang.com/prop-table-in-r/>